# Get Value from Keyboard Keys in WPF

Tags: wpf, keyboard

Please how can i get the value in the keyboard, i just tried :

```
   txbPinCode.Password = txbPinCode.Password + Key.NumPad7;
```

but the result in passwordBox is "NumPad7". how to  get "7" from key?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: what i want is, when i press a number on keyboard say number 7 i want the value of number key showing in passwordBox.

Comment: OMG why don't you just focus the passwordbox?

Comment: you don't understand me, what i want to tell you that i have a 'touch login page' with keypad on screen, if the user want to used the physical keyboard when he press the number i want the passwordBox get this number. i hope you understand me know,do you?

Answer (score 0):

Try [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey.aspx):

```
var keyEnum = Key.NumPad7;
var keyCode = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(keyEnum);

char keyChar;
if((keyCode >= 96) && (keyCode <= 105))
{
    //Numpad keys
    keyChar = (char)('0' + keyCode - 96);
}
else
{
    keyChar = (char)keyCode;
}

txbPinCode.Password = txbPinCode.Password + keyChar;
```

Comment: Hm.. it works for letters and the "normal" number keys, but not for the numpad. According to this (list of key codes)[http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html], you could just check if the virtual key value is between 96 and 105 (60 and 69 hex) to intercept numpad keys. I'll update my example.

Answer (score 0):

**This Solution is valid for only Numpads.**

```
MessageBox.Show( Key.NumPad7.ToString()[6].ToString());
```